# CSS for web pages in joomla

Tags: php, html, css, joomla

I am new to web design. I use Joomla 3 to create a bookshop website. I have designed my homepage the way I like using CSS, the problem is that i want to style other web pages on the website but i cant.

I am using a self made barebones template that has an index.php file and a style.css file. The CSS code I used for the homepage is in the style.css file. I need to create another css file for pages such as "about page" of the website so i can style it the way i want but I don't know how to do this.

The main menu has the following links: home, about us, text books, literature books, stationary, etc

Below is a snapshot of my index.php file.

```
<?php
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addStyleSheet($this->baseurl . '/media/jui/css/bootstrap.min.css'); /* to add bootstrap */
$doc->addStyleSheet($this->baseurl . '/media/jui/css/bootstrap-responsive.css'); /* to add     bootstrap responsiveness */
$doc->addStyleSheet('templates/' . $this->template . '/css/style.css');
$doc->addScript('/templates/' . $this->template . '/js/main.js', 'text/javascript');

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php     echo $this->language; ?>" >

<html>
<head>
<jdoc:include type="head" />

</head>

<body>
<div class='header'></div>
<!-- main container -->
<div class='main_container'> 

    <!-- Main Menu -->
        <div class='logo_main_menu'> 
            <div class='logo'> 
            </div>
            <div class='main_menu'> 
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-7" style="well" />
            </div>
```

Comment: If you're beginner, i suggest you don't use joomla. Learn the basic HTML and CSS first

Comment: You don't need to have a separate CSS file for each page.. every page can run off the same CSS file, that way you can store general layout rules, and apply them to all pages on your site. What I think you may be doing, is adding the body class to your CSS rules, which are only applying to the homepage. - Can you post some of your CSS rules?

Comment: Hi michael. I know I dont need to have seperate css for for each page. i just want to style other pages differently.

Comment: below is some code from my style.css

Comment: body 
{
 background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #f2f2f2;
}

.header
{
 background: url("../images/top.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
    position: relative;
 height: 10px
}

.main_container 
{
   height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 22px;
    width: 905px;
}

.mid_container 
{
    margin:20px 0px;
}

.main_content_area 
{
    width:905px;
 background-color:#ffffff;
}

Answer (score 0):

There can be unique cases where you need/desire several templates running on one Joomla install.  You could create an additional bare bones template, install, and then assign via template manager.

In template manager, you can assign a different template on every single page of your website.

So the solution you may be looking for would be to have a couple different templates to run your separate pages.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following code you can determine the front page and other pages and apply the changes required for each page.

ref: https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_determine_if_the_user_is_viewing_the_front_page

How to determine if the user is viewing the front page

There are some differences in 1.6/1.7/2.5 to avoid Strict Standards errors. Use the following code for a site where all content is in the same language:

```html
<?php
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) {
 echo 'This is the front page';
}
?>
```